# Get data to dataGridView in a form by entering data in another form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, datagridview

I am having 3 forms `InventoryManagementForm`, `PurchaseEntryForm` and `SalesEntryForm`. `InventoryManagementForm` has 2 buttons `Purchase` and `Sales` that navigates to `PurchaseEntryForm` and `SalesEntryForm` respectively. In `PurchaseEntryForm` there is a `ComboBoxList` which open list of products and a `NumericUpDown` used to count number of products to be bought. On clicked `Buy Now` the `ProductID`, `ProductName` and `Quantity` is should be added to the `SalesEntryForm`. I am printing the `SelectedItem` of `ComboBoxList` and `Quantity` of `NumericUpDown` in console by `Console.WriteLine` and it's printed correct. But after execution of `Add()` method which adds the values to `DataGridView` the data is not added and it's null maybe. What should I do so that the data is added to the `DataGridView`?

Code For `PurchaseEntryForm`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class PurchaseEntryForm : Form
    {
        // Initializing dictionary
        Dictionary<int, string> productDetails;

        // For counting product id, unique every time if someone adds a data
        private static uint _productID;

        // Reference for SalesEntryForm
        SalesEntryForm salesEntryForm = new SalesEntryForm();

        ProductDetails product;

        public PurchaseEntryForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public PurchaseEntryForm(SalesEntryForm salesEntryForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.salesEntryForm = salesEntryForm;
        }

        // Adding products on loading form
        private void PurchaseEntryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            productDetails = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            productDetails.Add(1, "CPU");
            productDetails.Add(2, "Monitor");
            productDetails.Add(3, "Keyboard");
            productDetails.Add(4, "Mouse");
            productDetails.Add(5, "Headphones");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in productDetails)
            {
                ListOfProductsCmb.Items.Add(pair.Value);
            }
        }

        private void BuyNowBtnHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BuyNowBtn.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        }

        private void BuyNowBtnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BuyNowBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(249, 249, 251);
        }

        private void BuyNowBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _productID++;

            product = new ProductDetails
            {
                ProductID = _productID,
                ProductName = ListOfProductsCmb.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                Quantity = int.Parse(ProductQuantityNud.Value.ToString())
            };

            salesEntryForm.ProductDetailsDgv.Rows.Add(new object[] { product.ProductID,
                                                       product.ProductName, product.Quantity });

            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Code For `InventoryManagementForm`:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class InventoryManagementForm : Form
    {
        SalesEntryForm salesEntryForm;
        public InventoryManagementForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PurchaseEntryBtn_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PurchaseEntryBtn.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        }

        private void PurchaseEntryBtn_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PurchaseEntryBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(249, 249, 251);
        }

        private void SalesEntryBtn_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SalesEntryBtn.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        }

        private void SalesEntryBtn_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SalesEntryBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(249, 249, 251);
        }

        private void PurchaseEntryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PurchaseEntryForm purchaseEntryForm = new PurchaseEntryForm();
            purchaseEntryForm.Show();
        }

        private void SalesEntryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            salesEntryForm = new SalesEntryForm();
            salesEntryForm.Show();
        }


    }
}
```

Code For `SalesEntryForm`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class SalesEntryForm : Form
    {
        public SalesEntryForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SalesEntryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image: InventoryManagementForm:][image: PurchaseEntryForm][image: SalesEntryForm]

Comment: In your `PurchaseEntryForm`, set `SalesEntryForm salesEntryForm = null;`. You cannot `new()` it. You have to use an existing reference, the one that *could* be passed in the Form's Constructor. But you never actually create `PurchaseEntryForm` using the overloaded Constructor, so you always use a new instance of `SalesEntryForm` which is not the one generated in `InventoryManagementForm`. So, create the instance in `InventoryManagementForm`, then pass it to `PurchaseEntryForm`. `Show()` the same instance when required. So, never use `new SalesEntryForm()` in `PurchaseEntryForm`

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get it what you tried to explain. Can you please write a small snippet so that I can understand it clearly? I am beginner that's why.. @Jimi